# MySQL avg count per month for current year (include months with no data)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a query for a bar-chart which displays a monthly overview of the number of orders.

The query I am using is correctly providing me with the breakdown per month but when I skipped a month, it is not providing a `0` for that month, just doesnt add it at all.

Since this chart is expecting 12 numbers, everything after the missing month would be off an inaccurate.

**Current Attempt:**

```
select Month(dateCreated) as monthID,
   Monthname(dateCreated) as monthName,
   count(dateCreated) as totalRewards
from reward
where Year(dateCreated) = '2018'
GROUP BY monthID
```

[image]

If we were to assume that it is currently `May 2018`, I would like to see Jan - May, current counts even if the month had no orders (April = 0).

Whats the best way to include all months that have happened so far in the provided year and then their appropriate count?

Comment: Just handle the missing months in your application code

Comment: you can do that in a query only if you join reward table with a table containing the months or with a subquery returning the numbers from 1 to 12

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to insert data while looping and inside array as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339949/how-to-insert-data-while-looping-and-inside-array-as-well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock a months table, then `LEFT JOIN` the `reward` table against it. To ensure you only get valid results, it's best to use a `SUM()` where not null rather than a `COUNT()` aggregate:

```
SELECT
    months.id as monthID,
    MONTHNAME(CONCAT('2018-',months.id,'-01')) as monthName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dateCreated IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as totalRewards
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS id
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5
    UNION SELECT 6
    UNION SELECT 7
    UNION SELECT 8
    UNION SELECT 9
    UNION SELECT 10
    UNION SELECT 11
    UNION SELECT 12
) as months
LEFT JOIN reward
   ON MONTH(reward.dateCreated) = months.id
   AND YEAR(dateCreated) = '2018'
GROUP BY monthID, monthName
ORDER BY monthID;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2de64/4)

Comment: Where does `stats.datetime_stamp` come into play?

Comment: Lol, it doesn't, fixed that up ta

Comment: hmm, this looks promising, just getting 0 results back when using the same data from the original screenshot

Comment: Sorry, a bug in the code, I shouldn't have put `MONTH(months.id)`, as we're comparing against the numeric value.

Comment: This provides me with `null`, `null`, `4` for the result set.

Comment: Gee, I'm firing on zero cylinders this morning. Try that edit, I've added a working fiddle as well

Comment: Sweet, this seems to be what I need! - Is there something I can add to there `where` so that it only gives me data up to the current month? For example, if it was `may 2018`, I don't need to see `June` - `December`. Only reason I ask is because this plugin I am using will have markers for months that haven't happened yet and it might be confusing. Other than that, this is great.

Comment: There's a few ways to do that, probably the easiest is to add a where clause `WHERE months.id <= MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`